# A function calls another function in CUDA C++

Tags: function, cuda, parallel-processing, call, global

I have a problem with CUDA programing ! 
Input is a matrix A( 2 x 2 )
Ouput is a matrix A( 2 x 2 ) with every new value is **3 exponent of the old value **
example : 
input : A : { 2,2 } output  : A { 8,8 } 
            { 2,2 }             { 8,8 }

I have 2 function in file CudaCode.CU :

```
   __global__ void Power_of_02(int &a)
{
    a=a*a;
}

 //***************
__global__ void Power_of_03(int &a)
{
    int tempt = a;
    Power_of_02(a); //a=a^2;
    a= a*tempt; // a = a^3
}
```

and Kernel :

```
__global__ void CudaProcessingKernel(int *dataA )    //kernel function  

   {  
        int bx = blockIdx.x;  
    int tx = threadIdx.x;  
        int tid = bx * XTHREADS + tx;  

    if(tid < 16)
    {
    Power_of_03(dataA[tid]);
        }
    __syncthreads();

   }
```

I think it's right, but the error appear : **calling a __global__ function("Power_of_02") from a __global__ function("Power_of_03") is only allowed on the compute_35 architecture or above**

Why I wrong ? How to repair it ?

Answer (score 6):

The error is fairly explanatory.  A CUDA function decorated with `__global__` represents a kernel. Kernels can be launched from host code.  On cc 3.5 or higher GPUs, you can also launch a kernel from device code.  So if you call a `__global__` function from device code (i.e. from another CUDA function that is decorated with `__global__` or `__device__`), then you must be compiling for the appropriate architecture.  This is called CUDA dynamic parallelism, and you should [read the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-dynamic-parallelism) to learn how to use it, if you want to use it.

When you launch a *kernel*, whether from host or device code, you must provide a launch configuration, i.e. the information between the triple-chevron notation:

```
CudaProcessingKernel<<<grid, threads>>>(d_A);
```

If you want to use your power-of-2 code from another kernel, you will need to call it in a similar, appropriate fashion.

Based on the structure of your code, however, it seems like you can make things work by declaring your power-of-2 and power-of-3 functions as `__device__` functions:

```
   __device__ void Power_of_02(int &a)
{
    a=a*a;
}

 //***************
__device__ void Power_of_03(int &a)
{
    int tempt = a;
    Power_of_02(a); //a=a^2;
    a= a*tempt; // a = a^3
}
```

This should probably work for you and perhaps was your intent.  Functions decorated with `__device__` are not kernels (so they are not callable directly from host code) but are callable directly from device code on any architecture.  The [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-language-extensions) will also help to explain the difference.